# OpenCV gpu perfomance

Tags: performance, opencv, gpu

I haven't got modern Nvidea gpu cards, but need to estimate perfomance for stereo matching algorithms in opencv before buying new cards.

Could your post here your results?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/2012) describes the OpenCV developer meetings each week. It is quite long, but you will find descriptions of algorithms, their performances, etc. You'll get an idea of how fast is GPU compared to CPU. Of course, it depends on images, algorithms, GPU quality and so on. But you'll get an idea.

A short and very approximate answer is that GPU is ~10x faster than CPU

Comment: Really large document) I try to run perfomance test in GeForce 9300m GS and got 0.8..1.3 increase fps in ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I found few pdf documents, with 10..50x, but if 5 or 10 users post here their real results it will be very easy not only for me.

Comment: I do dot have hands-on experience with CUDA, just hope this doc is helpful. I suppose the OpenCV guys have the best NVidia cards - NVidia sponsors them. So if you have a cheaper one, just beware :)

Comment: How did you come up with ~10x measure?

Comment: This is what they say in the results published in the link above. Of course there are many algorithms described there, so my appreciation is very rough.